# What are some of the risks associated with Septoplasty?

Tags: nose, ears-nose-throat-ent, nostrils, deviated-nasal-septum, septoplasty

I was experiencing nasal blockage for years and I've basically tried everything imaginable. Nasal drainage, nasal sprays (both prescription strength and over the counter), pills, breath-rite etc...And those they do help somewhat relieve the blockage a little, after an hour, it's back to square one.

One of my nasal passages is ALWAYS blocked and it rotates between the two. I recently went to an ENT to have it checked and he informed me I had a deviated septum. He recommended have it corrected through surgery (in-office procedure)

So what are the risks associated with this surgery? What's the average recovery time? I've never had surgery before so this will be my first time under the knife so I would love to here from people who've had this procedure and give me their in site!

Comment: i think i am late for answer, but i had same experience and septoplasty does not results +ve for me, and after some allergy blood test, i found i have allergic rhinitis, that do not need septoplasty, so please consult with some more doctor, that is is necessary in your case or not.